# spring security custome login page not displayed

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I am using spring security in jsf.

I want when i request the `Home.xhtml` , the `login.xhtml` displayed.

Here is my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Home.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="sajjad" password="200200" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

And this is `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And the `LoginBean.java`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String name;
    private String pwd;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String login() throws IOException {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("j_spring_security_check");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But when i request `http://localhost:8080/Home.xhtml` , then the `Home.xhtml` displayed without authenticates with defined `login.xhtml` page.

Comment: Although a file name may be arbitrary, the name `applicationContext.xml` for Spring security configuration file sounds somewhat strange. Don't you accidentally use the Spring configuration file to put Spring security configurations? `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` means that you are using JSF on top of Spring still your beans are annotated by JSF-specific annotations `@ManagedBean` `@SessionScoped` which appears to be unreliable. Besides, a session scoped bean as a login managed bean is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Tiny Gathering `spring security` and `application Context` configurations into one `xml` file isn't wrong and works. Because i tested it with [minimal http configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal) and had no problem.

Comment: @Tiny And about `session scope` you right, the `request scope` is enough for it.